# Display container view on event

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to use IB / storyboard (don't know how they call it now) with a container view as explained in the WWDC 2012 "Adopting Storyboards in Your App" video. Everything works fine, except that i would like to change a little bit the flow. I would like to perform the embed segue with an event. Is it possible without any line of code ?

It seems really basic, (a touch on a button that makes appear a child view controller is not a tricky case) so i think there may be a way but i can't find it.

Comment: The embed segue will occur immediately. Why not just hide the view until the button is touched?

Comment: If i have to do that, i prefer adding the child view controller by code when the button is touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The embedded controller will be instantiated at the same time as the main controller, but you can hide the view of the embedded controller in IB, then show it in your button's action method:

```
-(IBAction)makeVisible:(id)sender {

    [self.childViewControllers[0] view].hidden = NO;
}
```

If instead, you want to add the child view controller in response to an event, you can add it in code something like this:

```
    UIViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Child"];
    [self addChildViewController:child];
    [child didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    child.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150);
    [self.view addSubview:child.view];
```

Comment: There is not another way ? this one seems a little bit ugly and moreover require code, so i could do something prettier by adding the child view controller when i touch the button by code, this way i would not play with the hidden property. The embed segue can't be a custom segue that i could perform on touch and that could be used to make visible the child VC ?

Comment: @LiohAu, sure, you could add the child view controller by code, but from your question, it seemed you wanted to avoid code, and this way uses the least amount of code. I've updated my answer to show how you do it in code.